# Contract or something

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to MVC 5 and webapi in common.
As I am from the old WCF world I wonder if there is some way to show/display my methods from the api to clients?
Like a contract in WCF.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This link may help you : http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-api-help-pages

You can build help pages displaying how to use services you provide.